# All links to pjax except one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

I have this:

```
$(document).pjax('[data-pjax] a, a[data-pjax]', '#pjax-container');
```

to say any `<a data-pjax href...` must be passed to pjax. Is there a way to reverse this? I mean saying: pass all to pjax except the ones marked with no-data-pjax?

I tried this and it's not working:

```
$(document).pjax(':not([no-data-pjax] a), :not(a[no-data-pjax])', '#pjax-container');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:not('[no-data-pjax]')`:

```
$(document).pjax("a[data-pjax]:not('[no-data-pjax]')", "#pjax-container");
```

This will handle the links like: `<a href="..." data-pjax>...</a>` and will not select `<a href="..." data-pjax no-data-pjax>...</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue in my yii application. And I come with following solution:

I used

```
<a data-pjax="0" href="pathtoredirect" id="readthis" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
```

So you just need to add data-pjax="0" in anchor link. Hope my answer will help someone in future. :)